# Retrieving fields of email with logic apps / azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a use case where an HTML form is filled with user data and an email is sent to their email address, CC'ed to a logic app.

The logic app would receive this email and read only the values after `name:` and `email` form fields so that I can pass them along to another function.

How would one do this in a logic apps or within an Azure function?

Comment: Logic apps support  JSON, XML, flat files, and binary data. so if you are sending any data in these formats you will be able to parse and process them. Azure functions require a trigger( azure offers a bunch of triggers) based on which you will do some action. if you are creating this email then you will know the content . so you can probably create an object(json) with all the parameters and then handle it in logic apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [blog](https://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/14/logic-apps-tips-and-tricks-to-use-azure-functions-inside-logic-apps/) has great information on using Azure Functions from Logic Apps.
Assuming you have the logic app set up to receive emails, you then add a step to process emails in an Azure Function App sending the email content as an input.
Sample Input payload to nodejs webhook trigger:

```
{
  "email": {
    "emailBody": "Body×​​",
    "text": "Hello from Logic Apps"
  }
}
```

Note: "Bodyx" is the dynamic content representing the email body that was received in an earlier step.

Corresponding index.js in the function app:

```
  module.exports = function (context, data) {
  var email = data.email;
  // You can now do processing on the emailBody
  context.log('email body', email.emailBody);
  context.res = {
    body: {
      greeting: 'Hello !' + email.text
    }           
  };
  context.done();
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Pragna, that helps a lot thanks! Been struggling to find good resources and your example sums up a perfect way to implement what I want Cheers.